# npm run start try to execute "node" instead of node on a nestjs project

Tags: node.js, nestjs

Hello i have this problem when i want to execute `npm run start` with a nest project:

````
> collector@0.0.1 start
> nest start

'"node"' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file.```

I already have node installed but not in environment variable, I launch it from the installation folder. Does anyone had this issue ?

I tried to find where "node" was called like this, renaming all "node" to "nodes", but the error is the same, I tried it to isolate the problem but no effect.
````

Comment: So you don't have `node` installed to where you can just call `node dist/main` or similar?